# Java Exception and HTTP 500 Error

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, oauth, swagger

Is there any relevance with Java Exceptions at server side and `500` error code of `http` which is `Internal Server Error`. It happens because of `unhandled exceptions` in `catch` block or it could be because of of `unchecked` exceptions which is raised over `runtime`

How could I arrive to the conclusion, for me,- it is `Apache Camel` project which has `spring-boot-starter-parent` and has `Spring Quartz` Configured within. Basically `REST` calls through `OAuth 1.0` authentication probagates.

I am testing my application from `Swagger`. I am not able conclude that,

1. `OAuth 1.0` Authentication is succeeded or not
2. Error Handler Routines couldn't capture the specific,- `error code` in the project, as it is `unhandled` and `runtime exception` basically

Swagger gives following response with 500 error code.

```
"<Error><Message>An error has occurred.</Message><ExceptionMessage>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</ExceptionMessage><ExceptionType>System.NullReferenceException</ExceptionType><StackTrace>   at API.ExecutionTimeFilterAttribute.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)&#xD;\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecutedAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)&#xD;\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#xD;\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#xD;\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#xD;\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.&lt;CallOnActionExecutedAsync&gt;d__5.MoveNext()&#xD;\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#xD;\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#xD;\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#xD;\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.&lt;ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore&gt;d__0.MoveNext()&#xD;\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#xD;\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#xD;\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#xD;\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.&lt;ExecuteAsync&gt;d__2.MoveNext()&#xD;\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#xD;\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#xD;\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#xD;\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.&lt;ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore&gt;d__2.MoveNext()&#xD;\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#xD;\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#xD;\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#xD;\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.&lt;SendAsync&gt;d__1.MoveNext()</StackTrace></Error>"
```

Even with wrong `secret key`, `consumer key`, it is the same scenario.

I presume that keys are improper for both the scenario.

However I would like to know,

> is 500 error code is common for unhandled exceptions & unchecked
>   runtime exceptions or there we will be 400 series

How could I judge the testing scenario if http (500) error code is arisen other than custom java error code which handled in code and been responded back as part of response string for a `REST` calls.

Comment: post your try catch block which handles 400 series?

Comment: Code is obfuscated, so `try..catch` handles `400` series is it. In case `unchecked exceptions`, will it be `400` series or how it will be?

Comment: http 500 is also encountered when there is a memory leakage,so your server would be out of metaspace at that time and if that's the case then it will occur on every rest request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What you could do here is to add an ExceptionHandler and debug the
>   root cause of the exception. See:
>   http://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring OR 
>   http://zetcode.com/springboot/exceptionhandler/ OR http://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-exception-handling-for-rest-services

Most of the frameworks and libraries (used to build RESTful APIs) throw 500 error for any uncaught (or runtime) exception by default, and that is just because they can't decide the actual business logic.

But it is the server side developer's responsibility to handle any uncaught (or runtime) exception and convert them into proper HTTP response code as per REST API standards OR as per the business use cases. See: http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html for an ideal mapping of HTTP response codes, against use cases.

> P.S. It is like asking: should we store a set of integer values in an array
>   of Strings or in an array of integers. Language/Framework does not
>   mandate these nitty gritty details, right? (I mean sometimes they do,
>   with say, Generics in Java, but there is a limit :))